# JavaScript function call after page loading is not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarks

### Basic idea is to login a page with a single bookmark click

I'm trying to create a chrome bookmark which should

1. Load the page
2. Fill the details (Achieved by calling `fillDetails()` function)
3. Submit the form

**Code**

```
javascript:(function(){
window.location ="http://www.example/login.html";
window.onload = fillDetails();

function fillDetails() { 
    if(document.URL.indexOf("http://www.example/login.html") > -1){
        document.getElementById("username").value="uname";
        document.getElementById("password").value="pass";
        document.getElementById("login").submit();
        console.log("Success");
    } else {
        console.error("Cannot Insert values");
    }
}})();
```

**Error**

`fillDetails()` is executing before the page loads, but it **should be executed after page loads**

Answer (score 1):

Your are setting `window.onload` to the result of the execution of `fillDetails()`, instead of setting it to the function itself. Should be:

```
window.onload = fillDetails;
```

Comment: I tried in your way, but expected result is not achieved; I'm expecting a call back which should call fillDetails() after page gets fully/completely loaded

Comment: @sss12tup are you sure `fillDetails` is not getting called? Any errors in the console?